# sql function for checking if two persons have common ancestors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to solve the following problem: create a sql function that check if two persons have common ancestors, but I'm stuck.
I create

```
create type person as object
(
first_name varchar2(10),
last_namevarchar2(10)
);
```

and Persons table

```
create table client_iulia
(Person_Id varchar2(13)constraint pk_id_client primary key,
Mother_Id varchar2(13),
Father_Id varchar2(13),
Name person);
```

What  I am trying to do is a function  with three parameters (two people and search level) to return 1 if there are common ancestors and 0 otherwise)
Please, if anyone has any idea, help me.
Sorry  for my poor english.

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server but `varchar2` is Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive CTE is the way to go.  I think it is the easiest to understand.  There may be faster ways, but this should be clear how it works. I don't have access to an oracle server so I might have typos, I show two steps below so you can test and understand how it works.

1) Find all ancestors for a single input

```
with ancestors as
(
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia 
   WHERE Person_Id = @inputPerson
     UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia
   JOIN ancestors a on Person_ID = a.Mother_ID OR Person_ID = a.Father_ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM ancestors
```

2) Find all ancestors for two targets

```
with ancestorsA as
(
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia 
   WHERE Person_Id = @inputPersonA
     UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia
   JOIN ancestorsA a on Person_ID = a.Mother_ID OR Person_ID = a.Father_ID
), ancestorsB as
(
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia 
   WHERE Person_Id = @inputPersonB
     UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM client_iulia
   JOIN ancestorsB a on Person_ID = a.Mother_ID OR Person_ID = a.Father_ID
)
SELECT A.* 
FROM ancestorsA A
JOIN ancestorsB B ON A.Person_Id = B.Person_Id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helped me  to understand how to approach the problem

Comment: @JohnFlores - I just fixed a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's tricky. You need recursive queries to get all ancestors of either persons. As there are two parents, you will get pairs of mother and father, however, which you need to split into single ancestors. Then look if the sets have at least one ancestor in common. This statement gives you 1 when there is at least one common ancestor, else 0:

```
    with ancestors_of_person_1 as
    (
      select mother_id, father_id
      from client_iulia
      start with person_id = 1
      connect by person_id = prior mother_id or person_id = prior father_id
    )
    , ancestors_of_person_2 as
    (
      select mother_id, father_id
      from client_iulia
      start with person_id = 2
      connect by person_id = prior mother_id or person_id = prior father_id
    )
    select count(*)
    from
    (
      (
      select mother_id as ancestor from ancestors_of_person_1 
      union 
      select father_id as ancestor from ancestors_of_person_1
      )
      intersect
      (
      select mother_id as ancestor from ancestors_of_person_2 
      union 
      select father_id as ancestor from ancestors_of_person_2
      )
    )
    where rownum = 1;
```

EDIT: Here is an sqlfiddle. Person 1 and 3 have ancestor 122 in common, whereas person 1 and 2 have none in common. Try it: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/684ae/1/0)

Comment: I tried this option but I get an error  to person_id=1 and it asks to terminate the previous statement with a  semi-colon. I readed more about this error but  I do not know how to fix it.It is because the fild that start the selection has to be in the selected filds? Thank you very much

Comment: Hi John, sorry I confused table names. Maybe this caused the error. I have corrected my answer and added an sqlfiddle for you to try.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. I want to write this function in sql server but I wrote the instructions for creating a table in sql. I'm used to work with SQL and all the code you wrote works but I have and I try to make it work in SQL Server. Thanks!

Comment: I see. SQL Server does this differently. Look for: hierarchical queries in SQL Server.